# What's the largest PBM RPG ever run?

Tags: history-of-gaming, play-by-post

What play-by-mail (or email) RPG had the largest number of players?

I've recently been looking into "Net Games", play-by-post (not email) RPGs run by a company called Youentai in Japan in the 90s that seem to have peaked around ten thousand players, and was wondering if anything was larger. Looking around I could find a few English-language games, like Saturnalia, that claim to have had about 3000 players at one point, but nothing larger.

Because of the age and niche status of these games information is often not online, and I know any numbers will generally be unsubstantiated, but I'm curious about the history of large games.

**To clarify:** by "largest game" I don't mean a network where there are, for example, ten thousand people playing with the same rules but different sessions (like a network of chess players), but rather the largest number of people in a single shared world where all characters could (at least in theory) interact, much like a modern MMO server.

Comment: By a single PBM RPG, I take it that you mean a single instance of a game, not on a per-system basis?

Comment: Yes, as in a single shared-world game - "game" as in "a month-long game of Diplomacy", not "game" as in "D&D and Diplomacy are games".  I'll edit the question to try to make that more clear.

Comment: Do organized play programs count? Pathfinder Society and RPGA have a significant online following.

Comment: @Cyrad "Online" is very much not PBM.

Comment: Organized play seems really different because the actual "play" happens synchronously, so I think that's out. That said, I would consider PBeM games with slow-paced turns (weekly or so) basically the same as PBM RPGs. The Net Games I was referencing above had monthly turns.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Would you mind providing references to your examples?

Comment: I got the 3000 for Saturnalia figure from Wikipedia, but turns out there's no citation for that :/ . Can't remember exactly where I saw the 10k figure for Net Games but this link says there were over 3000 in the 1990 one (and they went on until 98 or so) https://togetter.com/li/1111849#c3748944

Answer (score 4):

The Dark Eye has in its motherland Germany a very old "[Briefspiel](https://de.wiki-aventurica.de/wiki/Briefspiel)" that started in 1988 and is run by the publisher. Nowadays it is exclusively play-by-email. At the hight of its life, it had far over 100 people that were in the same, organized game at the same time. It mainly focussed around playing a landed noble and organizing your own land, and started 2009 into the 4th instance, in 2014 they reported about it in their [official magazine](http://www.ulisses-spiele.de/produkte/1023/aventurischer-bote-166/), so it was running strong even then. Over the more than 20 years it has run, at least 7 members of the redaction have been recruited from the Briefspiel to join the writing team, while at least 5 members of the redaction/writing team have been very active in the game.

## Short game history

Two of the oldest lands that never changed hands and are still actively played by the first generation players are Ferdok and Beilunk (since 1988!), which belong to categories that hadn't been given out since the second recruitment in the early 1990s. The third run in 1996 changed from "apply your hero to become noble" to "invent a noble's history" and then one would be given an appropriate land, which is still the official process. While the game had no official organizer from 1997 to 2009 (ca 12 years), the players just continued and stemmed the organization effort themselves till 2009.

## Offshoots

Many of the big (officially sanctioned!) nobles did spawn sub-games to organize *their* court and attracting *unofficial* landed nobles that are chosen upon by these officially sanctioned nobles. At times these governers tie the acts of their subordinates into their own emails to their superiors and peers, increasing the number of *tied in* players at times massively - and lead to the rise of the regional wikis. It is hard to gauge the actual size of the unofficial crowd, just as hard as it is to get a list of the official nobles. My careful guess is though, that it is a number in the high 3 to 4 digit range.